# Ajax response rendering issue due to pagespeed

Tags: angularjs, ajax, nginx, pagespeed

I am using angular js for ajax call back and later rendering the response to 
  View.Sometimes the response not rendering to view and it is reflecting after 
  page load only which is not my desire scenario.

As per my current observations, we have enabled pagespeed in our NGINX server 
  and may be that is the case why it fails sometime to render the correct data.

Can anyone please suggest if any option available to disable page speed in 
  ajaxcallback or if any other solution is there that would be greatly 
  appreciated.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with PHP?

Comment: use `setInterval()` function

Comment: i am using setInterval() for 6 secs.But still the issue exists sometime.

Comment: As we are using PHP as server side code, we tagged it here too.

Comment: Unless you're having issues with the actual PHP code, remove that tag. You don't need to tag every single technology involved on the server.